# how to handle KEEPALIVE events?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, keep-alive, winsock2

I have a client-server app, and I set the keep alivce socket option on the server side. I understand to concept of the keep alive but how should I Handle the keep alive event, whether the keep alive mechanism recongnized a problem on the other end, and I want to close that socket which is connected to that client. 
I looked at WSAIoctl function but didn't really understood if it can solve my problem.

Iv'e got this example online :

```
tcp_keepalive   KeepAlive;
DWORD   dJunk;

//  Use socket level keep alive for about 5 minutes
//  Unless this is done Microsoft will not close the socket
//  in the event of a cable / VPN disconnection for 2 hours.
KeepAlive.onoff = 1;
KeepAlive.keepalivetime = 60000;
KeepAlive.keepaliveinterval = 60000;

WSAIoctl( soc, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, &KeepAlive, sizeof( KeepAlive ), NULL, 0, 
&dJunk, NULL, NULL );
```

I know it's very theoretical question but I really don't have any related code pieces.
so again, my question is how I'm supposed to handle a connection failure, like the other end is shuted down.

Comment: Do you use the built-in `SO_KEEPALIVE` option? Or do you have it your own protocol? Not that it really matters, when a keep-alive timesout you simply disconnect (`closesocket` on Windows) and possibly try to reconnect.

Comment: I use that to enable keepalive setsockopt(*s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *)&bOptVal, bOptLen). my question is how do I know whether the keep alive times-out, let's say I want to while iterate on that condition. @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 3):

You don't. There is no such thing as a 'keepalive event'. TCP does it all for you. If the keepalive timer times out, the connection will be reset.

Comment: Is there any way to get to know if the connection is reset ? maybe the socket become INVALID_SOCKET or some other indication @EJP

Comment: @LAvR The socket handle is not changed. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to close it, and there would be a socket leak. You will get ECONNRESET next time you send or receive.